# What's the meaning of " angry Ukrainian super"?

Tags: meaning

It's the line from "The Marvelous Maisel" Season 2 episode 2. It's a drama happened in 1958.

Here are the character's lines who's on a comedic gig:

> I don't want my own apartment.
>
> I-I don't feel ready, mentally, to have my own keys, my own plumbing, **my own angry Ukrainian super.**
>
> I don't feel prepared to take on that kind of responsibility alone.

So what's the meaning of "angry Ukrainian super" here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Super**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/super) is an informal term for [**building superintendent**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building_superintendent) (or just *superintendent* for short). A superintendent in North America is a person in charge of keeping a building in good condition. *Angry Ukrainian super* would then mean a superintendent who is of Ukrainian origin and who is constantly angry at the tenants (people paying rent for the apartments they live in) he has to work with. As far as I know, that's the typical image (stereotype) of superintendents, landladies and landlords in North America—they're always angry and complain about things.